# ASP.NET MVC 2 on mono

Tags: asp.net-mvc, mono

Is it possible to run the new ASP.NET MVC 2 Preview 2 on mono?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Yes. It was a bit tricky to compile from the ASP.NET MVC sources, but it works! See the [screenshot](http://gonzalo.name/tmp/aspnet-mvc2-mono.png).

However, this is not yet integrated/distributed with Mono. We will wait until the final release. If you want, I can upload the System.Web.Mvc.dll (2.0.0.0) I compiled and you can test it out (it needs to go in your app's bin folder until properly signed).

**Update:** The ASP.NET MVC2 code is now integrated in Mono (subversion trunk).

Comment: That would be nice if you could do that!

Comment: You need to put it in the bin folder of your ASP.NET MVC 2 application. Here it is: http://gonzalo.name/tmp/System.Web.Mvc.dll

Comment: ASP.NET MVC 2 shipping with Mono is good news! Can't wait to update from svn. =)

Comment: There are some issues with the included System.Web.Mvc even on mono 2.6.3. I made a repository with some fixes: http://github.com/sztupy/monosystemwebmvc

Comment: @SztupY: You should email mono-devel-list and let the maintainer know so the problems can be addressed.