# Embedded web server with integrated XML parser

Tags: xml, soap, https, embedded, web

I have a requirement to integrate a web server into an **embedded** device running **Linux** and am in the process of evaluating OSS and commercial offerings.

System requirements at not particularly tight: - Memory running set of up to 10MB, - Can spare 20%+ of a 300MHz ARM and more in bursts, - UI will be in jQuery and JSON, so would like to feed several hundred KB pages linking a dozen CSS and JS files in well under a second.

Feature requirements: - HTTPS support, - A 10+ concurrent connections, - Well-tested against DOS attacks.

Would **much appreciate** an integrated XML parser to base a SOAP implementation on.

Not a fan of PHP, but not certain about server-side Javascript either, and unfamiliar with Lua. So looking for suggestions for templating solutions, perhaps a Python-based stack.

Already reviewed [discussions on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3135745/web-technologies-for-an-embedded-server) and [lists on Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_lightweight_web_servers). Am aware of [thttpd](http://www.acme.com/software/thttpd/), [Mongoose](http://code.google.com/p/mongoose/), [Cherokee](http://www.cherokee-project.com/), [Appweb](http://appwebserver.org/products/appweb/embedded-web-server.html).

At this point I invite **detailed technical** suggestions and discussion of implementation choices, based on first-hand experince in production quality deployment.

Comment: Still evaluating options and would welcome more input. Appweb, Mongoose and Cherokee are still on the table, though thttpd is just too limited. Would like to understand how small an Apache configuration can be made, while still using Axis2 web services http://axis.apache.org/axis2/c/core

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When it comes to a simple python server stack, the combination I've heard most often from within the community for lightweight implementation is [CherryPy](http://cherrypy.org/) (to provide the thread-pooled WSGI server) with [Werkzeug](http://werkzeug.pocoo.org/) (to create the basic structure of the app)  Both are very slightly different takes on WSGI that speed development time considerably.

There some pretty good notes outlining basic python framework comparisons (albeit not in an embedded environment, but the emphasis was on lightweight deployments.) [at this question, in which Alex "the Machine" Martelli weighed in for these two.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2665313/python-framework-for-small-website)

If you can afford the overhead of the python interpreter (which I am assuming is ok as you included it in your eligible list), werkzeug is an excellent way to setup an app that consists of simple endpoints.  Responses can be mimetyped inline to aid in outputing your UI libs (Jquery, etc).  There are awesome examples on the Werkzeug docs.

One of the best resources I've been able to find on comparing WSGI servers (to satisfy your need for high concurrent connections and DOS survivability) can be found at [Nicholas Piel's blog post on the subject](http://nichol.as/benchmark-of-python-web-servers), where CherryPy ranks in as one of the best "bang-for-your-buck" resources to speed-wise.  The WSGI server in Cherry is deployment ready, and this can be used as the server process providing the environ to your Werkzeug app so you don't need to implement something heavier like Apache with mod_wsgi.  Cherry is easily capable of an average around 2000 r/ps with response times well under a second while under moderate load.

Since I don't know what kind of device you will be deploying this on, I should mention of course that both of these platforms are regularly updated, so this too should be considered if for whatever reason allocating network resources to update the device is impractical.

By combining python's `minidom` module (v2.6+) with the endpoint routing in Werkzeug, you should also benefit from very good development speed.  Constructing a complex url schema is simple using Werkzeug's `Map` feature, and the tutorial at their documentation page gives an awesome rundown on this.  Between the two, it shouldn't be too difficult to get your web service up and running.

Comment: I've seen Flask with Deform templates used successfully on a full-size platform. Huge thanks for a link to the nichol.as site with performance graphs, which give me an order-of-magnitude measurements.

Answer (score 1):

You have to decide which server side technologies that you'd use first. For an embedded system, you have severe resource constraints, so make sure you select the light weight technologies accordingly! Having said that Node.js is a great technology (http://nodejs.org/) that you may want to pay attention. I've seen some SOAP implementations for it as well. On the other side javascript based development could be very messy! You can try different solutions and start testing your system's functional behavior using tools like JMeter (http://jmeter.apache.org).

Some of the suggestions: Set up a lightweight http server (like Cherokee, lighttpd, etc) in your embedded system, then set up PHP (PHP has also some SOAP tools as well). Later change PHP with a Python or Ruby solution (like embedded Mongrel, etc). Find out how your system behaves under heavy load using JMeter.

Comment: Great pointer to JMeter, thanks! Not yet convinced about Javascript server-side development, even though respectable people do use Node. Apparently there are SOAP clients for Node https://github.com/milewise/node-soap and https://github.com/marcgreenstock/douche

Answer (score 1):

I presume that the purpose of your embedded web server is to provide
an administrative interface for configuration, operations and status.

For disclosure, our company builds and deploys administrative web
interfaces on many embedded systems with specs similar to what you
describe based on our product, Web. You can find out more about our
approach at http://uweb.workware.net.au/, and you can read a paper
I presented at the Embedded Linux Conference 2010
at http://workware.net.au/papers/embedded-scripting.pdf which provides
some detail of how we balance the size and performance concerns
with rapid deployment through scripting.

You have two broad options. The first is to use a framework such as µWeb, or
Barracuda server (mentioned above), or a an open source framework
such as luci (http://luci.subsignal.org/trac). The second is
to use a light-weight web server such as those you mention
above and then build your own framework (presumably based on jQuery
and JSON). The second option will take significantly longer and
security is a concern as you address XSS, CRSF and DOS attacks.

In any event, I strongly suggest you stay away from PHP, Python or
server-side Javascript.  These are all too resource hungry for a
300MHz ARM platform.

Why the requirement for XML and SOAP if your admin UI is going to
be jQuery and JSON? Do you have a separate requirement for SOAP
support? If so, gSOAP is probably a reasonable choice (it's been
a few years since I last used it).

Regarding https and 10+ concurrent sessions, note that the initial SSL handshake
is significantly resource intensive on and embedded platform. If you are
establishing new requests frequently (either because of new sessions, or because
requests aren't pipelined), the platform will struggle. You can probably only
establish 1-2 SSL connections/second.

Comment: The requirement for a SOAP server-side implementation is to support a legacy interface that exposes device properties and configuration in parallel to a browser-based UI.

Answer (score 1):

If you have only 10MB, then many of the suggestions are out of the question:  node and ruby will quickly exceed this footprint with only a small application. PHP will start at about 8MB minimum and can quickly go to 20+MB. We've seen one site with a 50MB PHP management app. Definitely not a good choice for embedded unless you have GB to spare.

I've used Appweb with ESP which is a c-language MVC framework and Ejscript which is server-side Javascript. Ejscript has XML parser and can handle the SOAP requirement. Appweb includes a very basic XML parser. You will need libxml if you want high level SOAP handling.

Appweb 4 has good DOS protections. You can limit the number of simultaneous requests from a single client with the LimitRequestPerClient directive. The LimitParseTimeout also helps to quickly close DOS requests that don't conclude their headers. The Appweb security sandbox has lots of directives for you to characterize your load - this helps for DOS and other security threats.

Your other choice would be to go pure Javascript and use Ejscript which has the Appweb http engine built into it.