# Is there a free alternative to IIS which supports HTTPS?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-2, iis-7, ssl, windows-vista, https

I develop on the following configuration:

> OS: Vista - Home Edition
>   IIS: IIS 7 - only in a simplified version without the administrative console, etc.

I'm working on an application that uses ASP.NET MVC 2.

The built-in Visual Studio Server is perfect for my work, but it does not support HTTPS.

Is there a free alternative to IIS that supports HTTPS, or whether it is possible to install the full version of IIS on Vista Home Edition?

Comment: im not sure about https but i know that web platform installer is a useful tool for getting iis for free on the lower end operating systems. this may not help at all sorry if so.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check out IIS Express, a cut down version of IIS 7.5:

> [IIS Express Overview on IIS.NET](http://learn.iis.net/page.aspx/868/iis-developer-express-overview/)

Comment: Thank you. I'll play with WebMatrix stuff and I'll let you know.

Answer (score -2):

In theory yes! You can use Mono and Apache: [ASP.NET MVC 2 on mono](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1684409/asp-net-mvc-2-on-mono) But why do you need Https on your development machine?

Comment: MONO - this is also a long way to go, and if that works? Why do I want to use SSL when coding? Because I want to make sure that everything works as it should ...